# Cannot locate the <SafeControls> section in the web.config

Tags: safe-controls

During installation process, after package is installed I get message on page "SolutionStatus.aspx" in Central Administration:

> Error: Cannot locate the `<SafeControls>` section in the web.config file
>   for this site. Controls in the specified assembly cannot be marked as
>   `<SafeControls>`

It is very strange, because provider of other packages on farm gets the same error. Any Suggestions?

(I installed SP2 on the farm a couple months ago, can it be source of problem?)

Comment: Can you check the web.config and see what's missing exactly ? Is it the safeControls definition in the section group or the actual safe controls node ? Is it also missing when you create a new site collection ?

Comment: Both are in place: in sectionGroup and SharePoint section as well. During installation process I get no errors, but webparts are not visible (so I can't test it) and as I said on a page I see the error. 
Wen I create site collection I don't encounter the error.

Comment: Very strange, maybe it's a permission issue or the file is locked or something ? I wonder why he would query the web.config, as the properties should all be on the SPSolution object already.